# How to require 1 or more of an argument in MAIN

Tags: raku

Right now, I have a `MAIN` sub that can take one or more string arguments. But I am using two separate parameters for `MAIN` to do it:

```
sub MAIN (
    Str:D $file,
    *@files,
) {
    @files.prepend: $file;

    # Rest of the program
}
```

Now I am wondering if there's a more idiomatic way to achieve this, as my current solution feels a little clunky, and not very Perly.

Comment: Do you want your script to take 0 arguments as well?  Or should it have at least 1 argument.  If the latter, than this is the way to do it, AFAIK.

Comment: At least 1 argument. I was thinking I could add a constraint to `*@files` to ensure it has more than 0 elements, but you can't add the `Str` type constraint (as in `Str *@files`) on it, and I want to have that for the default `USAGE` text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of "over answering" - my take on "Perly" is concise as possible without becoming obscure (perhaps I'm just replacing one subjective term with two others... :-)

If you have a "slurpy" array as the only parameter, then it will happily accept no arguments which is outside the spec you put in the comments.  However, a positional parameter is compulsory by default and [proto's](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/proto) are only necessary if you want to factor out constraints on all multi's - presumably overkill for what you want here. So, this is enough:

```
sub MAIN($file , *@others) {
    say "Received file, $file, and @others.elems() others."
}
```

This is close to what mr_ron put - but why not go with the default Usage message that MAIN kindly whips up for you by examining your parameters:

```
$ ./f.pl
Usage:
  ./f.pl <file> [<others> ...]
```

Some might say I cheated by dropping the *Str* type constraint on the first parameter but it really doesn't buy you much when you're restricting to strings because numerics specified at the CLI come through as type [IntStr](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IntStr) (a kind-of hybrid type) that satisfies a Str constraint.  OTOH, when constraining CLI parameters to Num or Int, Perl6 will check that you're actually putting digits there - or at least, what unicode considers digits.

If you're wanting actual filenames, you can save yourself a validation step by constraining to type `IO()`.  Then it will only work if you name a file.  And finally, putting `where .r` after the parameter will insist that it be readable to boot:

```
sub MAIN(IO() $file where .r, *@others) { ...
```

One short line that insists on one compulsory argument that is a filename referencing a readable file, with a varying number of other parameters and a useful Usage message auto generated if it all goes sideways...

Comment: Using the `IO` type constraint is interesting, hadn't really considered that one. I also greatly prefer to stick to the default `USAGE`, as this is one of the features I want to highlight with the code I'm creating.

Comment: "my take on "Perly" is concise as possible without becoming obscure" is, as you say, subjective and concept multiplying. It's also too constraining on "Perly" imo. But your point resonates nonetheless. Let me propose "razed" to name this approach. This is obscure but plausibly as concise as reasonable given that we can link to [the definition I intend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) and then argue about what "razed" means, including arguing about assumptions about assumptions, with the common ground being that we should strive to communally agree on exemplars of good razing.

Comment: Fwiw I think both your answer and Brad's are nice razors.

Comment: "This is obscure but plausibly as concise as reasonable..." - this sentence reminds me of trying to understand meta-object protocols :-)... but I take your point - trying to nail down perly was very unperly of me

Comment: Tyil - be aware that you get the effect by constraining to IO() including the parens.  Including the parens asks for coercion of the argument to the type.

Answer (score 10):

You could do it with a `proto sub`

```perl6
proto sub MAIN ( $, *@ ){*}

multi sub MAIN ( *@files ) {
    # Rest of the program
}
```

or with [sub-signature deparsing](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Destructuring_Parameters)

```perl6
sub MAIN ( *@files ($,*@) ) {
    # Rest of the program
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps good enough answer here:

```
sub MAIN(*@a where {.elems > 0 and .all ~~ Str}) {
    say "got at least 1 file name"
}

sub USAGE {
    say "{$*PROGRAM-NAME}: <file-name> [ <file-name> ... ]"
}
```

Based on docs here:
https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Constraining_Slurpy_Arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can also try and use simply dynamic variables:

```
die "Usage: $*EXECUTABLE <file> <file2>*" if !+@*ARGS;
my @files =  @*ARGS;
```

where `@*ARGS` is [an array with the arguments issued into the command line](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%40%2AARGS)

You can even use [`@*ARGFILES`, since they are actually files](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::ArgFiles#___top)